# How to pass multipart file and some fields to another api using resttemplate?

Tags: java, kotlin, java-8, resttemplate

I want to pass multipart file and username and email address to another rest controller. When I tried I am getting the error "required request is not multipart file".

rest template code :

```
    val headers = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>()
    headers["x-apikey"] = apiKey
    headers["content-type"] = "multipart/form-data"

    println("updateFileHeaderStatusByIdFlowUrl : " + uploadCsvFileFlowUrl)

    val body = LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Any>()
    body.add("multipartFile", multipartFile)
    body.add("backofficeUsername", backofficeUsername)
    body.add("backofficeUserEmailAddress", backofficeUserEmailAddress)

    val requestEntity = HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Any>>(body, headers)


    var response = restTemplate.exchange("localhost:8080/uploadCSVFile",
            HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String::class.java)

    System.out.println("response status: " + response.getStatusCode())
    System.out.println("response body: " + response.getBody())
```

rest api:

```
     @PostMapping("/uploadCSVFile/")
     fun uploadCSVFile(@RequestParam multipartFile: MultipartFile,
                  @RequestParam backofficeUsername: String,
                  @RequestParam backofficeUserEmailAddress: String) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `multipart/form-data` in method signature

```
@PostMapping("/uploadCSVFile/", consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA })
         fun uploadCSVFile(@RequestParam multipartFile: MultipartFile,
                      @RequestParam backofficeUsername: String,
                      @RequestParam backofficeUserEmailAddress: String) {}
```

Comment: change body.add("file", multipartFile.getResource()) instead of body.add("multipartFile", multipartFile)

Answer (score 0):

In case of header, add the below in case of java. setContentType() is used to set the Http Media Type to the server and in this it shoud be MultiPart.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
```